# Failed git push to AWS S3 Git Extensions

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, git-extensions, s3fs

I have an Amazon EC2 server with an S3 bucket mounted to `/mnt/git`.
There's a bare git repo in the bucket which I upload to using Git Extensions with Putty SSh.

Pushing to the server works without any warnings or errors but when I `pull` the remote master branch position is reset to the previous commit as though the push had failed. There's a message `(forced update)` in the pull log.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" pull --progress "aws" 
From ec2.ip.address:/mnt/git/Project
 + e158d62...be6f3f6 master 
-> aws/master  (forced update)
Already up-to-date.
Done
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this message because the push and pull commands aren't forced. The push log is below

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "aws"     master:master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To username@ec2.ip.address:/mnt/git/Project
   be6f3f6..e158d62  master -> master
Done
```

Edit:
I moved the repo to the ec2 local drive and the problem went away which implies the problem is with the s3 mount. I'm using fuse and s3fs to mount the drive. My fstab mount looks like this:
`/usr/bin/s3fs#my-bucket /mnt/git fuse default_acl=public-read-write,allow_other,use_cache=/tmp 0 0`

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: My presumption is this was a network timeout issue. S3 storage is too slow for this kind of activity. The solution is to use an EBS volume and mount it in this way http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html. S3 can be used as backup storage for the repo but shouldn't be used for the live central repo.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was network time out during the git commit process. Using fuse and s3 storage is just too slow. 
The solution was to mount an EBS device to the EC2 instance like this: [Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

Comment: so it's not advised to host a git repo inside of a s3fs mount??